# Matching the order of one array to another

Tags: c#, arrays, linq, sorting

I have an int array of ID's that are ordered properly. Then I have an an array of unordered objects that have ID properties.

I would like to order the objects by ID that match the order of the int array.

Something along the lines of

```
newObjectArray = oldObjectArray.MatchOrderBy(IdArray)
```

Would be most desirable

I feel like I should be able to accomplish this using LINQ but I have yet to find a way.

My current method doesn't seem very efficient since it has to query on every iteration of the collection. I suspect that performance can suffer for sufficiently large collections. Which eventually will happen.

Here is my current implementation:

```
    //this is just dummy data to show you whats going on
    int[] orderedIDs = new int[5] {5534, 5632, 2334, 6622, 2344};
    MemberObject[] searchResults = MyMethodToGetSearchResults();

    MemberObject[] orderedSearchResults = new MemberObject[orderedIDs.Count()];
    for(int i = 0; i < orderedIDs.Count(); i++)
    {
        orderedSearchResults[i] = searchResults
                                                .Select(memberObject => memberObject)
                                                .Where(memberObject => memberObject.id == orderedIDs[i])
                                                .FirstOrDefault();
    }
```

Comment: Could you show us some example input/output please?

Comment: I included example input in the question where I added the dummy data. The int array is a collection of ids, and the searchResults are a collection of my objects. The output would be the collection of objects sorted so that there IDs match the order of IDs in the int array.

Comment: Oh right, so if you had an array {-3, 4, -6} and yourobjects that had those IDs, you'd like to sort them based on that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A brute force implementation:

```
MemberObject[] sortedResults = 
      IdArray.Select(id => searchResults
                           .FirstOrDefault( item => item.id == id ))
```

However, this requires reiterating searchResults for every item in IdArray and doesn't deal too neatly with items that have duplicate ids.

Things improve if you make an ILookup of your search results, so that grabbing the correct search result for each item in IdArray is now O(1) time.

```
ILookup<int, MemberObject> resultLookup = searchResults.ToLookup(x => x.id);
```

Now:

```
MemberObject[] sortedResults = 
      IdArray.SelectMany(id => resultLookup[id])
```

Comment: Using a lookup was a wonderful suggestion. Thank you for that. It works much faster and is much cleaner in my opinion. The only thing I needed to do differently was add .ToArray() at the end of the select many to cast as a memberobject array

Comment: @MichaelTaylor3D : I've pretty much duplicated a Linq Join here. I'm not sure what guarantee Join provides about the final sort order, but using the current Join implementation `IdArray.Join(searchResults, x=>x, x=>x.id, (a,b)=>b)` gives identical results by near identical methods.

Comment: I used a join to get my initial results and while I was getting the results I wanted, they were not in the correct order.

Comment: The implementation orders by the items on the left of the Join (outer collection).

Comment: Yep thats why, my left was the object array, it seems if I flip things around I should be able to reduce some redundancy in my code.